# Nodejs & pkg - How to get if the project is compiled?

Tags: node.js

I compiled a Nodejs project with [pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg) but I'm trying to find out, in run time, wether the project is compiled or not.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. May be useful to someone else:

```
if (process.pkg) {
    // runtime is compiled with pkg
} else {
    // runtime is not compiled with pkg
}
```